# Insert and update with core SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a database that I don't have metadata or orm classes for (the database already exists).

I managed to get the select stuff working by:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import ColumnClause
from sqlalchemy.sql import table, column, select, update, insert
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc

db = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://pytest')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=db)
session = Session()

list = []
list.append (column("field1"))
list.append (column("field2"))
list.append (column("field3"))

s = select(list)
s.append_from('table')
s.append_whereclause("field1 = 'abc'")
s = s.limit(10)

result = session.execute(s)
out = result.fetchall()

print(out)
```

So far so good.

The only way I can get an update/insert working is by executing a raw query like:

```
session.execute(<Some sql>)
```

I would like to make it so I can make a class out of that like:

```
u = Update("table")
u.Set("file1","some value")
u.Where(<some conditon>)

seasion.execute(u)
```

Tried (this is just one of the approaches I tried):

```
i = insert("table")
v = i.values([{"name":"name1"}, {"name":"name2"}])

u = update("table")
u = u.values({"name": "test1"})
```

I can't get that to execute on:

```
session.execute(i)
```

or

```
session.execute(u)
```

Any suggestion how to construct an insert or update without writing ORM models?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As you can see from the [SQLAlchemy Overview](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/intro.html#id1) documentation, sqlalchemy is build with two layers: `ORM` and `Core`. Currently you are using only some constructs of the `Core` and building everything manually.

In order to use `Core` you should let SQLAlchemy know some meta information about your database in order for it to operate on it. Assuming you have a table `mytable` with columns `field1, field2, field3` and a defined `primary key`, the code below should perform all the tasks you need:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import table, column, select, update, insert

# define meta information
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
mytable = Table('mytable', metadata, autoload=True)

# select
s = mytable.select() # or:
#s = select([mytable]) # or (if only certain columns):
#s = select([mytable.c.field1, mytable.c.field2, mytable.c.field3])
s = s.where(mytable.c.field1 == 'abc')
result = session.execute(s)
out = result.fetchall()
print(out)

# insert
i = insert(mytable)
i = i.values({"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"})
session.execute(i)

# update
u = update(mytable)
u = u.values({"field3": "new_value"})
u = u.where(mytable.c.id == 33)
session.execute(u)
```

Comment: After searching for 2 days found most of that also anyway tanks for clearint it up for me

Comment: Why session and not transaction? From docs, session should be used with ORM, right?

Comment: how would multiple values...an array of dictionaries? do you have to iterate?

Comment: @mike01010, yes, you can pass a list of dictionaries for multiple sets of values. See documentation for [`values(...)`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Update.values)